# Add and call javascript function at runtime from within innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnethighcharts

I am using dotnet.highcharts to create a chart at runtime:

I use an ajax call an receive formatted html as a result. This is what I get back:

```
<div id='bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f_container'></div><script type='text/javascript'>
var bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f;
function TestFunction() {
    bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo:'bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f_container', defaultSeriesType: 'line' }, 
        title: { text: 'Test' }, 
        xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'] }, 
        series: [{ data: [12, 23, 1, 9, 34, 54] }]
    });
}
</script>
```

Now I am putting this inside a div element (where data is the above snippet):

```
$(myDiv).innerHtml = data;
```

Next I need to call the function `TestFunction()`

How can I do that? It lives inside myDiv like this:

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="float:left">
    <div id="bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f_container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f;
      function TestFunction() {
        bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: { renderTo: 'bbb55283bfc3440a96c7ae26e130173f_container', defaultSeriesType: 'line' },
            title: { text: 'Test' },
            xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'] },
            series: [{ data: [12, 23, 1, 9, 34, 54] }]
            });
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TestFunction` doesn't "live inside the `div`".  JavaScript isn't part of the markup in that manner.

As soon as the function is defined:

```
function TestFunction() {
    // code
}
```

It is available from then on as a global function on the `window` object.  So from anywhere else on the page you can invoke it:

```
TestFunction();
```

Of course, if this `div` is *repeated* in any way and you're assuming some kind of namespacing of functions within `div`s, then you'll find that not to be the case in practice.  If the function is globally defined *again* anywhere in the document then that second definition will simply overwrite the first one.

Comment: But why am I not able to call TestFunction()? I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: TestFunction is not defined" when I try to call it from console

Comment: @buddybubble: You don't provide any information about that in the question, so I can only guess.  It would seem, clearly, that when you try to call it the function *hasn't* been defined.  Maybe I misunderstood, is the *JavaScript code itself* being returned by the AJAX call?  That's definitely going to cause some interesting scenarios, especially if there is more than one instance of it.  But evaluating JavaScript returned by AJAX could require a little bit of trickery.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097558/proper-way-to-execute-javascript-returned-via-ajax-no-jquery

Comment: My case seems to be almost the same as the one you linked. Like I said, I am getting a mix of html and js as a result from an ajax call, see my first code snippet. I am putting this with innerHtml inside a div. I then want to call one part (TestFunction) of the code I just inserted into the div

Comment: @buddybubble: This answer in particular seems like a good approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097791/328193  If you have the entire response as a jQuery object then you should be able to extract the `script` element from that object.  Then you can create and append a new `script` tag like in that answer.

Comment: Thanks that did it! I just dont understand why I have to do that. Can't I call the function - as you said in your initial answer- directly?

Comment: @buddybubble: Admittedly this is a scenario I've never encountered, but I'm not entirely surprised by the result.  It seems reasonable to me that a browser's default action would not be to *execute* JavaScript code that's added to the DOM after the initial page load.  This could probably be abused fairly easily, so you'll definitely want to be careful with the *source* of that JavaScript code being executed.  For example, if you ever execute *user-provided* code (even if they don't type it themselves), you could be open to XSS and similar attacks.

Comment: Well in my case I want to invoke a JS function that is returned as a result of something that is calculated inside my asp.net controller, no parameters can be passed to it from the user so I should be on the safe side